# connection to http//10.0.2.2 refused in android studio connecting with google app engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

I made an app in android and used java servlets module as a backend and deployed app on google app engine and accessed it from android app,it worked perfectly fine.
Then I tested the app on physical device but I got error connection to http//10.0.2.2 refused .
Now I am getting this error on emulator without running the app on physical device.I googled a lot but not getting help in this context.Thanks

Comment: What has running your app on an emulator to do with not running your app on a device? And how would your app connect with your app deployed on google app engine? Don't understand a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10.*.*.* is a range reserved for private intranets. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses). You're not going to be able to connect to private ranges from deployed app. From a physical device, you'll only be able to connect to a 10.*.*.* address if you're inside that private network.

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is a special ip used by apps running on an emulator which want to connect with a server on the same machine as the emulator runs.